# Change Right and Left click functionality on MapboxGl

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to change mouse click functionality on mapboxGl. I need to implement right click panning on map, but there is no documentation about it. So I tried to disable map rotating on right click and enable panning but nothing worked, it just disabled rotation but panning is not triggered.

I want to know if there is a way to programmatically start and stop dragging/panning, I know you can enable it, but I need to actually start panning.

Want to make it clean and easy, I figured you can add listener on mousemove then change map boundaries but it doesn't look nice. Is there any easier way to start dragPan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you want to change left and right click if you want it for left-handed, they should change the mouse settings.
But, anyway, it's possible to make right click for dragging the map.

```
map.dragPan.disable();
map.dragRotate.disable();

var isMoving = false;
var offset;
map.on("contextmenu", (e) => {});
map.on("mousedown", (e) => {
  if (e.originalEvent.button === 2) {
    isMoving = true;
    offset = e.point;
  } 
});
map.on("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (isMoving) {
    map.panBy([offset.x - e.point.x, offset.y - e.point.y], {
      duration: 0,
    });
    offset = e.point;
  }
});
map.on("mouseup", (e) => {
  isMoving = false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cs09g/cnz4xhkt/4/

Comment: the left and right click changes are the requirements for the client. I am developing part of a system where right click panning is a standard for all maps. Not sure why :) 
Anyways thanks for an answer. I did something like this, but your solutions is more compact.

Comment: Or try to custom mapbox-gl engine to use left click event as right click event vice versa.